# GWT - Adding visibility true/false handler

Tags: java, events, gwt, event-handling, visibility

Is there a simple way to add handlers/listeners to widgets so that the change to visibility can be detected ?
Or do i have to create a system of my own ? (which means creating other widgets that wrap needed widgets and trigger events when setVisible(...) is called)

Comment: An alternative is to not make your application logic depend on state of widgets, but make the same event that causes the widget to hide trigger an application event that other things listen to - if hiding the 'login' button because the user just authenticated, other code shouldn't listen to that to update, but be triggered by the same thing that hide the button in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard widgets have their own listeners and handlers.  If your application requires your own events then you have to define custom user defined events, listener and handlers.

Answer (score 0):

overite setVisible(boolean visible)
extend UIObject or use deffered binding