# FlexTable visibility listener

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

I have a control panel, where I do a panel switching between other 2 panels.
I would like to add a visibility listener to one of the panels: when become invisible or removed from parent than do something - a callback.

```
        parentPanel.remove(panel_1);
        parentPanel.add(panel_2);
```

And inside of panel_1 I would like to have a callback, but maybe others can remove him from UI.

What is the name of the function which I should use it, to add the callback? - can't find it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396983/gwt-adding-visibility-true-false-handler it is a "NO way"? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every widget in GWT has `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` methods. You can override them.

Comment: Note that this doesn't inform you when someone calls `.setVisible(false)` - you only get notified when the widget is attached or detached. Also, there is an `AttachEvent.Handler` that canbe added to any `Widget`.

Comment: +1, this is perfect, this  I needed and searching for keywords "visible" and "invisible" " listener" lead me to wrong way